loop to select the date closest to another date, for multiple variables
For each MRN ID, I would like to select the date (in OBSERVATION_DATE), in association with various columns (i.e. hdl, ldl, and vldl) that is closest to the dates listed in multiple other columns (i.e. Base, SixMonths, TwelveMonths, and TwentyFourMonths). So for example, for the rows that report HDL data, I would like to assess the dates found in OBSEVATION_DATE to find the date closest to Base, SixMonths, etc. There should be 4 new columns created for that example (one for each of the 4 time points listed). Additionally, for that example, I want another set of 4 columns created that have the value associated with the date that was identified in the other 4 new columns. So in total for my sample data,there should be 24 new columns (See below).
The algorithm should look for only the observations that have data in a given column as potential selections for dates that are closest to Base, SixMonths, TwelveMonths, and TwentyFourMonths. For example, if a row does not have data for HDL, it should not be considered as part of the selection pool to choose a date from. Not all dates given for a person will have data in all the columns I am concerned about. therefore, it would not be useful to rely solely on an algorithm that chooses a date for a person regardless of whether there is data for that variable at that date.
HDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to Base,
HDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to SixMonths,
HDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwelveMonths,
HDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwentyFourMonths,
HDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to Base,
HDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to SixMonths,
HDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwelveMonths,
HDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwentyFourMonths,

LDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to Base,
LDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to SixMonths,
LDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwelveMonths,
LDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwentyFourMonths,
LDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to Base,
LDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to SixMonths,
LDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwelveMonths,
LDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwentyFourMonths,

VLDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to Base,
VLDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to SixMonths,
VLDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwelveMonths,
VLDL OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwentyFourMonths,
VLDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to Base,
VLDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to SixMonths,
VLDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwelveMonths,
VLDL value associated with OBSERVATION_DATE date closest to TwentyFourMonths,

Here is my data:
structure(list(MRN = c(15842, 15842, 15842, 19463, 19463, 19463, 
19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 
19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 19463, 34025, 34025, 34025, 
34025, 34025, 34025, 37465, 37465, 37465, 68874, 68874, 68874, 
76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 
76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133, 76133), OBSERVATION_DATE = structure(c(18289, 
18289, 18289, 16073, 16073, 16073, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16536, 
16536, 16536, 16821, 16821, 16821, 17196, 17196, 17196, 17604, 
17604, 17604, 19114, 19114, 19114, 19338, 19338, 19338, 19060, 
19060, 19060, 19730, 19730, 19730, 17326, 17326, 17326, 17331, 
17331, 17331, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17339, 
17339, 17339, 17347, 17347), class = "Date"), HDL = c(NA, 47, 
NA, 40, NA, NA, NA, 43, NA, 38, NA, NA, NA, 41, NA, NA, 48, NA, 
NA, 45, NA, NA, 44, NA, NA, 42, NA, NA, NA, 56, 16, NA, NA, NA, 
34, NA, 34, NA, NA, 31, NA, NA, 33, NA, NA, NA, 32, NA, NA, NA
), LDL = c(NA, NA, 83, NA, 92, NA, 107, NA, NA, NA, NA, 112, 
93, NA, NA, 96, NA, NA, 109, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76, 56, NA, NA, 
141, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49, 55, NA, NA, NA, NA, 57, NA, 53, NA, 
NA, NA, 59, 55, NA, NA, NA, 55), VLDL = c(14, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
46, NA, NA, 30, NA, 30, NA, NA, NA, 28, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, 28, 
17, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, NA, 35, NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, 24, NA, 
24, NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, 23, NA, NA, NA, 26, 22, NA), Base = structure(c(17647, 
17647, 17647, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 
17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 17032, 
17032, 17032, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18894, 
18894, 18894, 19431, 19431, 19431, 16751, 16751, 16751, 16751, 
16751, 16751, 16751, 16751, 16751, 16751, 16751, 16751, 16751, 
16751, 16751, 16751, 16751), class = "Date"), SixMonths = structure(c(17830, 
17830, 17830, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 
17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 17215, 
17215, 17215, 18760, 18760, 18760, 18760, 18760, 18760, 19077, 
19077, 19077, 19614, 19614, 19614, 16934, 16934, 16934, 16934, 
16934, 16934, 16934, 16934, 16934, 16934, 16934, 16934, 16934, 
16934, 16934, 16934, 16934), class = "Date"), TwelveMonths = structure(c(18012, 
18012, 18012, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 
17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 17397, 
17397, 17397, 18942, 18942, 18942, 18942, 18942, 18942, 19259, 
19259, 19259, 19796, 19796, 19796, 17116, 17116, 17116, 17116, 
17116, 17116, 17116, 17116, 17116, 17116, 17116, 17116, 17116, 
17116, 17116, 17116, 17116), class = "Date"), TwentyFourMonths = structure(c(18377, 
18377, 18377, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 
17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17762, 
17762, 17762, 19307, 19307, 19307, 19307, 19307, 19307, 19624, 
19624, 19624, 20161, 20161, 20161, 17481, 17481, 17481, 17481, 
17481, 17481, 17481, 17481, 17481, 17481, 17481, 17481, 17481, 
17481, 17481, 17481, 17481), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")


In your example data, the first MRN 15842 has three identical OBSERVATION_DATE values of 2020-01-28. Which is closest to Base 2018-04-26?

In your example data, many HDL/LDL/VLDL values are NA for the same MRN/OBSERVATION_DATE, e.g. the first three rows. Should these be coalesced to a single row?

I don't think it is necessary for them to be coalesced into a single row. I am wanting to find the OBSERVATION_DATE closest to (example) Base for EACH of those columns (i.e. HDL, LDL, and VLDL). So it shouldn't be a choice between those first three rows of which one is closest to Base. Because I need the date chosen when there is data for HDL for 15842, then another date chosen when there is data for LDL for 15842, and 3rd date chosen when there is data for VLDL for 15842. They might end up being the same dates in the newly created columns.

Even if they end up by chance of being the same dates in the new columns, it doesn't matter. It is just the date for each separately (HDL, LDL, and VLDL) that is closest to Base, SixMonths, TwelveMonths, and TwentyFourMonths (separately).

But I presume if a row shows NA for one of those measurements, it should not be considered for being the closest observation; I presume only non-NA values represent an observation.

If one measurement was 20 days before a milestone and another was 20 after a milestone, which should be linked?

Correct. However, I don't necessarily rely on there being an observation for all 3 variables at each date either. Often there will be, but not always. Additionally, I have other columns that do not align so well with these (e.g. glucose measurements tend to be taken at different times than lipid panels- these 3 variables of HDL, LDL and VLDL represent lipid panels). Let me update my description to mention that a value being present in the column is what should be used as an indicator of an observation for the given column. I do not plan on keeping these original columns either.

As for which to choose if one is 20 days before and 20 after, I will leave it to your discretion to choose what to do with those. My supervisors do not care too much. Often I just let algorithms choose randomly which to keep

I'm not sure I follow all the requirements but I think this essentially gets what you want.
I make one table with all the valid non-NA measures. I make another with all the milestone dates for each patient.
Then I full_join these, arrange in order of date difference, and keep the first observation for each MRN/milestone/measure.
(For large data with, say, thousands of observations per patient, this full join could produce output that is too large to handle. As of dplyr 1.1.4 in mid-2023, we can't directly get the "closest" match with a join, but we could join with the closest date that is <= and separately join with the closest date that is >=, and pick between those as a final step.)
library(tidyverse)
df_measurements <- df |>
  select(MRN:VLDL) |>
  pivot_longer(HDL:VLDL, names_to = "measure", values_drop_na = TRUE)

df_patient_timeline <- df |>
  select(-(OBSERVATION_DATE:VLDL)) |>
  distinct() |>
  pivot_longer(-MRN, names_to = "milestone", values_to = "DATE")

df_patient_timeline |>
  full_join(df_measurements, join_by(MRN)) |>
  arrange(MRN, milestone, measure, abs(DATE - OBSERVATION_DATE)) |>
  slice(1, .by = c(MRN, milestone, measure))

Result:
     MRN milestone        DATE       OBSERVATION_DATE measure value
   <dbl> <chr>            <date>     <date>           <chr>   <dbl>
 1 15842 Base             2018-04-26 2020-01-28       HDL        47
 2 15842 Base             2018-04-26 2020-01-28       LDL        83
 3 15842 Base             2018-04-26 2020-01-28       VLDL       14
 4 15842 SixMonths        2018-10-26 2020-01-28       HDL        47
 5 15842 SixMonths        2018-10-26 2020-01-28       LDL        83
 6 15842 SixMonths        2018-10-26 2020-01-28       VLDL       14
 7 15842 TwelveMonths     2019-04-26 2020-01-28       HDL        47
 8 15842 TwelveMonths     2019-04-26 2020-01-28       LDL        83
 9 15842 TwelveMonths     2019-04-26 2020-01-28       VLDL       14
10 15842 TwentyFourMonths 2020-04-25 2020-01-28       HDL        47
# ℹ 62 more rows

I presume your intended output is a wider version of this data. If we add the code below...
... |> 
pivot_wider(names_from = c(measure, milestone), 
            values_from = c(OBSERVATION_DATE, value))

we get this super-wide table with (I think) the columns you sought:
# A tibble: 24 × 26
     MRN DATE       OBSERVATION_DATE_HDL_Base OBSERVATION_DATE_LDL_Base OBSERVATION_DATE_VLDL_Base OBSERVATION_DATE_HDL_SixMonths OBSERVATION_DATE_LDL_S…¹ OBSERVATION_DATE_VLD…² OBSERVATION_DATE_HDL…³ OBSERVATION_DATE_LDL…⁴ OBSERVATION_DATE_VLD…⁵
   <dbl> <date>     <date>                    <date>                    <date>                     <date>                         <date>                   <date>                 <date>                 <date>                 <date>                
 1 15842 2018-04-26 2020-01-28                2020-01-28                2020-01-28                 NA                             NA                       NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
 2 15842 2018-10-26 NA                        NA                        NA                         2020-01-28                     2020-01-28               2020-01-28             NA                     NA                     NA                    
 3 15842 2019-04-26 NA                        NA                        NA                         NA                             NA                       NA                     2020-01-28             2020-01-28             2020-01-28            
 4 15842 2020-04-25 NA                        NA                        NA                         NA                             NA                       NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
 5 19463 2016-08-19 2017-01-30                2017-01-30                2017-01-30                 NA                             NA                       NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
 6 19463 2017-02-18 NA                        NA                        NA                         2017-01-30                     2017-01-30               2017-01-30             NA                     NA                     NA                    
 7 19463 2017-08-19 NA                        NA                        NA                         NA                             NA                       NA                     2017-01-30             2017-01-30             2017-01-30            
 8 19463 2018-08-19 NA                        NA                        NA                         NA                             NA                       NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
 9 34025 2020-11-11 2022-05-02                2022-05-02                2022-05-02                 NA                             NA                       NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
10 34025 2021-05-13 NA                        NA                        NA                         2022-05-02                     2022-05-02               2022-05-02             NA                     NA                     NA                    
# ℹ 14 more rows
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​OBSERVATION_DATE_LDL_SixMonths, ²​OBSERVATION_DATE_VLDL_SixMonths, ³​OBSERVATION_DATE_HDL_TwelveMonths, ⁴​OBSERVATION_DATE_LDL_TwelveMonths, ⁵​OBSERVATION_DATE_VLDL_TwelveMonths
# ℹ 15 more variables: OBSERVATION_DATE_HDL_TwentyFourMonths <date>, OBSERVATION_DATE_LDL_TwentyFourMonths <date>, OBSERVATION_DATE_VLDL_TwentyFourMonths <date>, value_HDL_Base <dbl>, value_LDL_Base <dbl>, value_VLDL_Base <dbl>,
#   value_HDL_SixMonths <dbl>, value_LDL_SixMonths <dbl>, value_VLDL_SixMonths <dbl>, value_HDL_TwelveMonths <dbl>, value_LDL_TwelveMonths <dbl>, value_VLDL_TwelveMonths <dbl>, value_HDL_TwentyFourMonths <dbl>, value_LDL_TwentyFourMonths <dbl>,
#   value_VLDL_TwentyFourMonths <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

